# How can you cast T to a class to match a "where T : class" constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I'm running into a generics issue while working on a generic Dependency Injection handler (a base Service Locator).

**Edit 1 (for clarity)**

Okay so I'm actually using SimpleInjector as a DI resolver and it has the class constraint on it's GetInstance method, so here is some more complete code:

```
  public T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
  {
     try
     {
        // works
        return _container.GetInstance<T>();
     }
     catch( ActivationException aEx )
     {
        return default( T );
     }
  }

  public T GetInstance<T>()
  {
     try
     {
        if( typeof( T ).IsClass )
        {
           // does not work, T is not a reference type
           return _container.GetInstance<T>();
        }
     }
     catch( ActivationException aEx )
     {
        return default( T );
     }
  }
```

**Edit 2** - final code since it looks strange in comments:

```
  public T GetInstance<T>()
  {
     try
     {
        if( typeof( T ).IsClass )
        {
           return (T) _container.GetInstance(typeof(T));
        }
     }
     catch( ActivationException aEx )
     {
        return default( T );
     }
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps if we knew more about why you are interested in doing this, apart from a returning null example...?  Might be a better way to structure it.

Comment: Please see edit 1 for why I want to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one more helper method? please find test class below

```
public class Test
{
  public T GetInstance<T>() where T : class
  {
    return (T)GetInstance(typeof(T));
  }

  private object GetInstance(Type type) 
  {
     return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
  }

  public T GetEvenMoreGenericInstance<T>()
  {
     if( !typeof( T ).IsValueType )
     {
        return (T)GetInstance(typeof(T));
     }
     return default( T );
  }
}
```

Comment: That actually works, thanks. I forgot about casting to T: `public T GetInstance<T>()
      {
         try
         {
            if( typeof( T ).IsClass )
            {
               return (T) _container.GetInstance(typeof(T));
            }
         }
         catch( ActivationException aEx )
         {
            return default( T );
         }
      }`

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can't do this, at least not directly. The compiler would have to do a lot of work to absolutely guarantee that T will always be a class in your situation, so it won't let you pass it as a generic type parameter without applying the same type constraint to GetEvenMoreGenericInstance.

You could accomplish this through reflection, or create a non-generic overload of GetInstance which takes a Type as a parameter. I would recommend the Type parameter option, or restructuring your code completely to eliminate the need to call this method.

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to find a variant of `GetInstance`, then call the appropriate one.

The following example makes calls to static methods, but you could extend it:

```
namespace Scratch
{
    internal class Foo
    {
      // A class to create
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static T GetInstance<T>() where T : class, new()
        {
            return new T(); // Or whatever...
        }

        public static T CallGeneric<T>(Func<object> f)
        {
            var method = f.Method;

            var converted = method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T));

            return (T) converted.Invoke(null, new object[] {});
        }

        public static T GetEvenMoreGenericInstance<T>()
        {
            if(!typeof(T).IsValueType)
            {
                return CallGeneric<T>(GetInstance<object>);
            }
            return default(T);
        }

        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var a = GetEvenMoreGenericInstance<int>();
            var b = GetEvenMoreGenericInstance<Foo>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the use of reflection :)